# Determine type of an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code:

`var parent = links[i].parentNode;`

I'd like to write something like:

```
if (parent.typeOfElement == "div") {
 ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Btw, what you want is not the *type* of a node, but the *name*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName), which is (for elements) the same as [`.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName).

So:

```
if (parent.tagName === "DIV") {
   //
}
```

Note that the tag name is supposed to be returned in uppercase for HTML, but in XML (including xhtml) it is supposed to preserve the original case - which for xhtml means it should be lowercase. To be safe, and allow for any future changes to your document type and allow for non-standard browser behaviour you might want to convert to all upper or all lower:

```
if (parent.tagName.toUpperCase() === "DIV") {
   //
}
```

In my experience `.tagName` is used much more often, but I gather that [some consider `.nodeName` a better choice](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23) because it works for attributes (and more) as well as elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (parent.nodeName == "div") {
    ...
 }
```

See: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml

Comment: For element nodes in an HTML document, [nodeName is effectively an alias for tagName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095). While HTML tag names aren't case sensitive, it is common (though possibly not universal) for browsers to return tag names in upper case as [suggested in the DOM Core standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-104682815). To ensure consistency, use `.toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` to ensure the tagName has a particular case.

Comment: I tried [it but](http://pastebin.com/YzeYi44U) alerts nothing, though there are div parents of a.